# SSL Connection with webclient.getpage from Java client error 403

Tags: java, tomcat, https, httpclient, ssl-certificate

I have an annoying problem that maybe someone has already addressed.

I have a solution that connects to an HTTPS page (you download the certificate in case of lack or variation), provides the certificate password and then sends data.

Until recently I used this code that worked perfectly

```
Protocol authhttps = new Protocol("https", new org.apache.commons.httpclient.contrib.ssl.AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory(keyStoreKeys, qCertPassword, null, qCertPassword), 443); 
Protocol.registerProtocol("https", authhttps);

WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3);

DefaultCredentialsProvider userCredentials = (DefaultCredentialsProvider) webClient.getCredentialsProvider();
userCredentials.addCredentials(qUsername, qPassword, host, 443, realm);
webClient.setCredentialsProvider(userCredentials);

HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(SiteHttpsUrl);
```

The certificate is downloaded to the client; if I go to login page with a OpenConnection, does not give errors. The certificate is NOT self-signed, and I do not use proxy.

But now the manufacturer's protocol (`org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.Protocol` with `JDK 1.6.0_18` and `HTTPclient 3.1` or higher) which contained `AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory` is deprecated and no longer able to supply, resulting in the protection error 403, the launch of `getPage`.

I have to use the `WebClient` to simulate clicks of buttons and links.

What can I do?